# Mapping vs composition

Tags: java, oop

If I have two classes with a one-to-one relationship, when's a good time to use mapping.

```
class A { ... }
class B { ... }
class C { 
    Map<A,B> a2b;
}
```

And when's a good time to use composition?

```
class A {
    B myB;
}
class B { ... }
```

Would the answer change if the relationship was one-to-many and many-to-many?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on how widespread this `A` to `B` relationship is used throughout the project.

If lots of different areas of the project will need to know the `B` associated with `A`, then it is best if this is simply a part of the `A` object.  On the other hand, if this association is only used in one part of the project, then you should create the `HashMap` in that part of the project to store the relationship.

This answer does not change if it's a one-to-many or many-to-many relationship.

Comment: +1 Clear and concise, thanks! And if in the future this relationship might be removed, then maybe mapping would be better right?

Comment: If you know now that the relationship is only temporary, that would be a good reason to lean towards the mapping solution.

Answer (score 1):

Using a `Map` will increase complexity of the whole thing.

This because in your example one of the two classes (`A`) *owns* the other, this is true either for composition (since you need the `A` to retrieve its `B`) either for the mapping (since you need the key `A` for value `B`).

So if there's not an explicit need to used a map, just avoid it.

For the cases 1:N, M:N you should always consider what kind of operations you will need to do on the objects, since having a third object that just manages the mapping between the `A` and `B` is not a really OO solution, you could use composition.

One-to-Many can be modeled with a `List<B>` inside `A` while Many-to-Many is the only case in which having a mapping could be good, since otherwise you would have to explore both objects to understand their mappings.

Shortly: if you will access the data from a `A` perspective (`A` owns `B`) then you don't need to have an external mapping, otherwise you will but it should be bidirectional (two hashmaps).

Comment: A owns B in the composition example, but not the mapping.  The Map doesn't increase the complexity if the solution calls for it.  There's also nothing to say that the third object only manages the mapping.  This is a general design question - don't look too much into the specifics of the examples, which are pretty general to begin with.  A bidirectional mapping should only be used if the design calls for it.

Comment: That's what I said, it adds unnecessary complexity if you don't really need to use it, it depends on the design of specific problem involved. In any case A owns B also in the mapping example, since you can't retrieve an A object with its associated B object, you would need 2 maps to manage both directions (`Map<A,B> a2b` and `Map<B,A> b2a` with all according operations)

Comment: Your comment assumes a more "database-driven" approach than a OO one. A specific mapping object should be used just when really necessary, otherwise it is just a waste of allocations and time, you can surely avoid using it 90% of the time.

Comment: `A` does not own `B` in the mapping example.  Neither object needs to know about each other to use them as a key-value pair in a `HashMap`.  This is part of the power of the `HashMap`.

Comment: Yes, I wasn't talking about the "owning" concept from database relationship or composition in OOP.. not a conceptual one but a practical one.

Answer (score 0):

The map is good for **many-to-many** relationships (like join tables in database design). As long as your **one-to-one** or **one-to-many** relation does not need special attributes, there's no need to use a third class (this third class would model the relation itself).

Make an association, maybe a bi-directional one, if you need to *look from both directions*:

---

```
public class A {
  private B b;
  public A(B b){
    this.b = b;
    b.setA(this);  // for bi-directional association
  }
}
```

---

```
public class B {
  private A a;
  public B(){};
  public void setA(A a) {
    this.a=a;
  }
}
```

Comment: This isn't a pattern that I use often with a bi-directional association.  In fact, I try to avoid it as much as possible.  I like my classes to be hierarchical in nature, so that if one class knows about another, that class doesn't know about the first.  I have found very few examples where I need to violate this.